# Finding the values corresponding with user input from a list of tuples

Tags: python

As a foreword, I'm quite new to python, and coding in general.

I'm trying to get the following code to find the specific values in the `foodgroups` tuple that match with user input (ie: Dairy, Nuts, and Grain) and attach them to `Output` (ie: Dairy and Nuts). The line with `Output` was gotten from [another website](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-find-the-tuples-containing-the-given-element-from-a-list-of-tuples/) when I was first making this. The code works when the user provides an input that only contains one item without any symbols or spaces (ie: Dairy) but anything extra causes `Output` to be blank when printed.

```
userinput = input("Enter foodgroups ate in the last 24hrs : ").title()
foodgroups = ("Dairy","Nuts","Seafood","Chocolate")

Output = list(filter(lambda x:userinput in x, foodgroups))

if foodgroups[0] or foodgroups[1] or foodgroups[2] or foodgroups[3] in userinput:
  print(Output,"is present in your list, " + userinput)
else:
  print("Negative.")
```

I've thought of swapping around `foodgroups` and `userinput`, but that results in a TypeError, and turning the tuple into a string has `Output` always return blank.

I've asked others how to fix this, but they've had no better luck. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If userinput is a comma separated string then split it and use a list:

```
userinput = input("Enter foodgroups ate in the last 24hrs : ")
foodgroups = ("Dairy","Nuts","Seafood","Chocolate")
uin = userinput.split(",")
grp = []
for x in uin:
  if x in foodgroups:
    grp.append(x)
```

`grp` is the user defined foods in foodsgroup

Comment: Or, if libraries are allowed, you can do `import pandas as pd` then do `grp=pd.Series(uin).isin(foodgroup)` to avoid the loop

Answer (score 0):

The main thing is that you want to use `split` to separate individual words from the user input into a list of words.  I also swapped `x` and `seafoods` in your lambda.

If the user separates each word by one or more spaces, here's how to change your code to work:

```
userinput = input("Enter foodgroups ate in the last 24hrs : ").title()
foodgroups = ("Dairy","Nuts","Seafood","Chocolate")

userfoods = userinput.split()

Output = list(filter(lambda x: x in userfoods, foodgroups))

print(Output,"is present in your list, " + str(userinput))
```

Answer (score 0):

As other's mention, you need to use `split()` to separate individual items in the input:

```
userfoods = userinput.split()
```

But even after that your `if` condition isn't correct:

```
if foodgroups[0] or foodgroups[1] or foodgroups[2] or foodgroups[3] in userinput:
```

The thing to realize here is that `or` and `in` are operators that **only** work with the immediately adjacent 2 values. We can add parentheses to see how this works:

```
if (((foodgroups[0] or foodgroups[1]) or foodgroups[2]) or (foodgroups[3] in userinput)):
```

This means that `foodgroups[0] or foodgroups[1]` evaluates to just the value of `foodgroups[0]`, so `foodgroups[1]` is basically ignored. This isn't what you want. Instead, you need to check `in` for each item:

```
if foodgroups[0] in userinput or foodgroups[1] in userinput or foodgroups[2] in userinput or foodgroups[3] in userinput:
```

But as you can see this gets very lengthy. So using a loop or list comprehension or generator expression can reduce the amount of code you need to write as others have already shown.